# Safari Action Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, safari-extension

I need to create an action extension which can be used in conjunction with the iOS Safari app. When the user presses the action extension in Safari, I want my app to be launched and have the URL of the current page open in safari to be passed to it as a parameter. How do I do this?

Comment: Have u implemented this ?